# Powershell Copy-Item not copying

Tags: powershell

I have to following directory structure:

```
fold1
 - file1
 - file2

fold2
 - file1
```

I am trying to test to see if the folders are identical, and if they arent, copy fold1 to fold2 and overwrite any different files. This is what I have tried:

```
$fold1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\fold1
$fold2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\fold2
$isDif = Compare-Object $fold1 $fold2
if ($isDif -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Folders Are Identical"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Folders Are Different"
    Copy-Item -Path $fold1.FullName -Destination $fold2.FullName -Recurse -Force
}
```

But when I run it, it says the folders are different, but it doesn't copy anything over. No errors or anything, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i, just do it

```
 $path1 = "C:\temp2\*"
 $path2 = "C:\temp3"

 Copy-Item -Path $path1 -Destination $path2 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Continue
```

Comment: This is much more efficient than my answer.  I just did not know if Alan wanted the check the folder contents before the copy.

Comment: It is unnecessary to check. If the files exist, they will not be overwritten. :)

Comment: I agree if you are going to override the files regardless.

Comment: "Compare-Object $fold1 $fold2" compare only path difference, not content files difference ;) My code did the same thing

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using `robocopy` instead:

```
robocopy c:\fold1 c:\fold2 /s
```

Comment: I've spent so long trying to get `copy-item` to work that I'm starting to think this or xcopy really is the best answer...

Comment: I found it hard to believe but yes - `Copy-Item` is actually unreliable...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would recommend doing the task in powerhsell.  It makes it much easier if you create path variables, that way you are not trying to insert records into a directory object.

```
$path1 = "C:\fold1"
$path2 = "C:\fold2"
$fold1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $path1
$fold2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $path2
$isDif = Compare-Object $fold1 $fold2
if ($isDif -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Folders Are Identical"
}
else 
{
    Write-Host "Folders Are Different"
    ForEach($file in $fold1)
    {
        if($fold2 -notcontains $file)
        {
            Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $path2 -Recurse -Force
        }
    }
}
```